# Этимология слов "крыло, крылья"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, получается, что слово "крыло" никак не связано со словом "летать", а с чем тогда оно связано? Интересно было бы узнать этимология.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Крыло. От общеславянского kridlo, восходящего к той же основе, что и словенское krilo, польское skrzydlo, латышское skriet ("бежать, лететь"). Изменение корневой гласной с и на ы объясняется влиянием глагола крыть. Из этимологического словаря Крылова.